# Web form with dynamic preview

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

What I have is an HTML form (inside its own DIV) with 12 inputs (6 text inputs, 3 radio inputs, 2 select dropdown inputs, and 1 image file input).

What I want to do is have a second DIV to contain a "live preview" which will be updated as the form is filled out (i.e. when an image file is selected the preview DIV updates to display that image and then if a radio button is selected the preview DIV will display the radio value on top of the image file).

**For clarification**: the image file will be shown as the background behind the other 11 inputs.

Would this be Javascript or another language? And how would I implement this?

Comment: yes javascript (or jQuery if you don't want to reinvent already-made solutions for cross browser support, especillay for AJAX)

Comment: Could you perhaps provide some basic boilerplate code for how I could do it via JS?

Comment: You can all find in the jQuery official documentation. Take a look at [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). I advise you to make of this website your friend if you want master jQuery developement.

Comment: you are welcome. Let us see what you advanced. Good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by doing the following using jQuery:

- create a DIV called "Preview" which contained all sub DIVs for each form field.
- set the CSS for each DIV as position:absolute and added an ascending z-index value so that nothing was displayed skewed.
- For the "live preview" of the image, I used the following code:

  ```
  $(function() {
      $("#uploadFile").on("change", function()
       {
         var files = !!this.files ? this.files : [];
       if (!files.length || !window.FileReader) return; // no file selected

       if (/^image/.test( files[0].type)){ // only image file
          var reader = new FileReader(); // instance of the FileReader
          reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]); // read the local file

          reader.onloadend = function(){ // set image data as background of div
          $("#PreviewDIV").css("background-image", "url("+this.result+")");
          }
        }
    });
  });
  ```
- For all other fields I used generic code to update "Preview DIV" for that element on "keyup":

  ```js
  $(function(){
      $('#textboxID').keyup(function(){
          $('#PreviewID').text($(this).val());
      });
  });
  ```